How is the system bus different from pipe call?
Is the system bus and pipe call same in a computer ? What are the differences between them ?

Trying to grasp a thorough understanding of hardware and lower-level system concepts by asking on "Computer Science Educators" is rather off-topic for this forum, and will be a very slow and probably frustrating process. I'd recommend to search for some good tutorials or attend an appropriate course.

The "system bus" is a hardware concept and determines how components connect and transfer data amongst themselves in some computers. For example, a CPU and the memory chips (or controller) might sit on the system bus so that fetch and store transfer data between them.
The word 'pipe' is usually used to describe a software concept in Unix and other operating systems of chaining programs together, sending the output of one program to the input of another. For example "dir | print" might be saying to extract the current directory and send it to a printer (rather than the screen, perhaps). And "dir | count" might send the number of lines in the output of dir to the screen. (hypothetical examples, not real). The vertical bar is the pipe operator of unix.
